# How to split a column in two base of the 8 first number of a value in this column

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

I want to split a columns in two base of the 8 first number of each row. For example, my column look like this

```
       Col1
    7002500101
    7002500104
    7002500103
    7002600101
    7002500101
    7002500102
```

And i want to separate de 8 first number for the other like this.

```
      Col1            Col2
    70025001           01
    70025001           04
    70025001           03
    70026001           01
    70025001           01
    70025001           02
```

I find how to do it when we already have separation sign ( -,_,; etc.), but not for my situation.

Comment: Here is quick and dirty solution `cbind(substr(Col1, 1, 8), substr(Col1, 9, 10))`

Comment: Is this a string or an integer column?

Comment: i.e., First column should be just `df$Col1 / 100` while the second could be `round(100 * (df$Col1 / 100 - floor(df$Col1 / 100)))` (if this is an integer column)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe `df` containing your `col1`, you can use `gsub` and regular expressions to achieve the desired result:

```
df$newcol1 =  gsub("(^\\d{8}).*","\\1",df$col1)
df$newcol2 = gsub("^\\d{8}(.*)","\\1",df$col1))
        col1  newcol1 newcol2
1 7002500101 70025001      01
2 7002500104 70025001      04
3 7002500103 70025001      03
4 7002600101 70026001      01
5 7002500101 70025001      01
6 7002500102 70025001      02
```

The first expression keeps the first 8 digits `(^\\d{8})`, while the second expression keeps whatever comes after the first 8 digits `(.*)`.
The newcol1 and newcol2 columns will be of type character. If you want them as numeric, wrap the `gsub` in `as.numeric(..)`.